# REST service and JSON

Tags: rest, json

How can I retrieve via REST service in SharePoint item column values in JSON:

This is my snippet:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("my list")/items/getbyid(3)',
  type: 'GET',
  header: {'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
  success: function(data) { alert(data.title); }
});
```

It's not working, any help?

Comment: You really need to put some more context into your questions - from that snippet its really not clear how you are calling the services. We can guess, but might be wrong so include a little more detail

Answer (score 7):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script>
 function restEndPoints2013(){

$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://site/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('listName')/items(3)", 
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){  
                  alert(item.Title);
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
</script>
<body>
<script>
restEndPoints2013();
</script>
```

Dump this into an HTML editor and upload it to a server and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through data.d.results:

```
function(data) {
$.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
//get item property
var strTitle = result.Title;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nadeem, I tried it and I got the error in JavaScript that it can't get the property results for the undefined data.d

It can't know what is d in the data.

Comment: any more ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use jQuery for this. At first you build your Query String:

```
//For the Element with the ID 1
var urlQuery = "https://www.url.i/site/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Listname?$filter=ID eq 1";
```

Then you can access the items from the list:

```
 $.getJSON(urlQuery,
    function (data) {
       $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item) {
          var title = item.Title;
       });
    });
```

EDIT 1: Fixed it, should work for SP2010.

EDIT 2: For SP 2013 you can use this Query String:

```
http://url.i/sites/siteName/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('listName')/items?$filter=Id eq 1
```

Then you should get the element as XML. If you put

> accept: application/json;odata=verbose

in the HTTP-Header you get the result as JSON

Here are some more information about [Rest in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mbauer, but I need to pass a parameter to the list with the ID of the item and get the title, so what am using is something like this: 
$.ajax({ 
url: '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("my list")/items/getbyid(3),
type: "GET",
header: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
success: function(data){
alert(data.title);},

but it's not working

Comment: the data returned in xml not json..!

Comment: what SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: Foundation 2013

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use $.ajax instead of $.getJSON and replace "header: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}" by " dataType: 'json' " in order to get the response in JSON format. Besides, try to add to your ajax the parameter "async: false" to make the request synchronous because you are trying to get the value from an empty object.

Comment: Won't work very well against SharePoint REST API without the header proposed by mbauer!